# How to get top div to fill remaining height after bottom div rendered? (without flexbox)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

Three divs each above the other, within a parent container. Top div is fixed height. Bottom div has content that takes up an unknown amount of vertical space but needs all content within it to display. Top div should fill remaining vertical space. Every

```
<div id="container"> // 100% of visible window height but should not overflow
   <div id="top"> // Fixed height
   </div>
   <div id="middle"> // Use remaining vertical space
   </div>
   <div id="bottom"> // Unknown height but contents should all be shown
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to support recent-ish legacy browsers (e.g. IE9+) & mobile browsers (e.g. Android 4.4+), so flexbox based layouts are out. I tried Javascript (using JQuery) to try and set

```
middle div height = container height - (top div height + bottom div height)
```

but for some reason the browser was mis-reporting the bottom div height during page render (latest Chrome on Win 7) so result came out wrong. And I'd like to avoid JS if possible (tho am open if a solution works).

Need to support as many desktop and mobile browsers as possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For old browser , where `flex` cannot be used , **`display:table`can be a fall back**  but layout will be able to grow past window's height where content is too long to be shown at once.

A CSS only  mix using `flex` and `table` as a fallback where `flex` is not supported: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BdWXpp

Below, snippet with `display:table`/`table-row` CSS only (which works for almost any browser ***(IE8 and next)***

```css
html,
body,
#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
  background: turquoise;
}

#container>div {
  display: table-row;
}

.buffer {
  display: table-cell;
  /* display is optionnal but element is required in HTML to keep layout as a single column and allow vertical-align to content*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

#top {
  background: orange;
  height: 100px;
}

#middle {
  height: 100%;
}

#bottom {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="top">
    <div class="buffer">top 100px, test me full page and in any medias
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
    <div class="buffer">Use remaining vertical space
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    <div class="buffer">Unknown height<br/> that fits <br/>to content to hold
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```