# Make a div fill the rest of the page (cross-browser)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser, height

I just want to make a div below some fixed texts, and I want the div to fill exactly the height of the page, and I want it to work cross-browser... It is hard to believe how much work such a nature task requires.

I tried [this code](https://jsbin.com/vanuxaqiwu/16/edit?html,output), which adjusts the height by jQuery. It works well in Chrome, but it does not work perfectly in Chrome: if we scroll down, we could see it does not automatically restore to the initial position.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0
    }
    .rb .myME {
      background: grey
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="rb">
    <div class="top">1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/></div>
    <div class="myME">abc</div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(".myME").css({
      height: (($(document).height()) - $(".top").height()) + 'px'
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have a perfect solution (CSS or jQuery) cross-browser?

Comment: By perfect cross-browser solution, do you mean one that includes old/archaic IE versions (6-9) as well?

Comment: No... I will be satisfied of a solution that works with modern Chrome, IE and Safari.

Comment: easy peasy -> https://jsfiddle.net/om38udk3/

Comment: @adeneo it does not work well in Safari.

Comment: Why not ?.......

Comment: is the  top div have fixed size ?

Comment: @MohamedAdel yes, fixed size

Comment: It really sounds like you're looking for a "sticky footer" kinda thing, there should be tons of examples of pure CSS footers that can be extended up to the content any which way you choose

Comment: @adeneo In Safari, when you scroll down, you will see the height is almost infinite...

Comment: CSS could do this without flex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577564/how-to-get-top-div-to-fill-remaining-height-after-bottom-div-rendered-without/45577776 so it is compatible also with old IE8

Comment: Whether or not you accept the given answers, here's one with your original HTML and CSS, with only minor JS modifications (added window load resize scroll listener, and hid the div before adjusting size and showed it after) and one new META tag (to force IE11 to not use compatibility view - just in case); though I can't test in new Safari on Windows... apparently Apple no longer provides new Windows Safari installers. https://jsbin.com/rehiyugupu/edit?html,output

Comment: @mark.hch This jsbin works well in Chrome. In Safari, it is better than my jsbin, after scrolling down, it does restore to the initial, but there are some very obvious flashing...

Comment: @SoftTimur How about now? I removed the hide() and show() calls, and used the window's height instead of the document height. I also set it to auto height if the window is smaller than the .top element. https://jsbin.com/deyivibina/edit?html,output

Comment: Now, I come to the initial problem for Safari: after scrolling down, it does restore to the initial position. @mark.hch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for older and newer browsers , the `display:table` properties could match your requirement.

```css
html,
body,
.rb {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.rb {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.top, .myME {
  display: table-row;
}

.buffer {
  display: table-cell;
}

.top .buffer {
  background: lightblue;
}

.myME .buffer {
  background: tomato;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="rb">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="buffer">
      1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="myME">
    <div class="buffer">
      abc
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the `.buffer` div is to make sure that each of your rows are made of a single cell to avoid layout to be split also in columns.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution works for me in Chrome and Safari at least. Actually I want to embed a Monaco Editor inside `myME`, but the height does not work well with your solution ([JSBin](https://jsbin.com/ceriyorota/2/edit?html,output)), do you have any idea? Do you want me to post another question for this?

Comment: would this be a solution for the moment ? https://jsbin.com/tevizuviwe/1/edit?html,css,output looks like your editor gets bigger than the area where it is suppose to stand. or https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZJJBym but your editor seems buggy (scrollbars unreachable)

Comment: @SoftTimur ?? maybe you should test in a stand alone document online to be sure that's all fine (too many frames in the way i guess)

Comment: I always test it in a standalone page on my side... it is very odd that the codepen works well in Chrome, but does not show the editor at all.

Comment: and the jsbin solution works fine in Safari, but not very well in Chrome. I think the way is to figure out why the codepen solution does not show the editor in Safari.

Comment: might be some security or filtering of codepen. open both jsbin and codepen, so scripts should be in the browser cache. (it happens sometines with image too with codepen ...)

Comment: I copied your codepen to a standalone html file... the file works in Chrome, but does not show the editor in Safari, though I can inspect the editor element. I will put a link here.

Comment: You should update your question including the link for Safari testing to be seen. I do not have Safari where i stand :(

Comment: Here is the [file](https://www.matrixlead.com/test/ME.html), I will post another question, and put the link here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625660/let-monaco-editor-fill-the-rest-of-the-page-cross-browser

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make that div under that text you need to do some css there you can find many tutorials because it is in basics:

Use `position relative` to parent div and `position absolute` to div that u want to move under text.

If you want to use full height you don't need jquery use `VH - viewport` height as `height: 100vh;` to have full height of any devices.

I am not sure does VH works everywhere but it does for me in chrome, fox, edge

By W3schools it works here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: Please provide a working example, I have tried `vh`, it is even less good than jQuery cross-browser.

Comment: Then I don't understand your questions: 
I just want to make a div under some fixed texts- under or below?
And I want the div to fill exactly the height of the page- which div, myme or rb?
For myme you are subtracting height of top div from full height. So I don't understand which div you want to make full height?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "below", I want "myME" fill the rest of the page.

Comment: Then @MohamedAdel solution works well for me in Safari (that I just dowwnloaded) works same as in others...

Comment: Where is Mohamed Adel's solution?

Answer (score 0):

If top div is a fixed size ( just change size in both heights in top div and calc function )  you can try this :

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.rb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.myME {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc( 100% - 100px);
  background: grey;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="rb">
    <div class="top">1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/></div>
    <div class="myME">abc</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: flex only requires :flex:1; on the child suppose to fill space remaing. height is not needed. the easiest solution for nowdays browsers.